# How to create redshift table using JSON file

Tags: sql, mysql, amazon-redshift

I am trying to create a table in Redshift on a JSON file but each time I am getting errors in my SQL Script.

JSON File:

```
[{"name":"abc","age":23,"dif":23.89},{"name":"pop","age":28,"dif":98.89}]
```

I first created an empty table in Redshift and then tried to copy data from s3.

Query 1(Create empty table)

```
CREATE TABLE raw.age_group_table(
name VARCHAR(255)
name INTEGER,
dif FLOAT);
```

Query 2 (COPY DATA to the table)

```
COPY raw.age_group_table
FROM s3_location
IAM_ROLE 'arn:aws:iam::123:role/MyRedshiftRole'
JSON 'auto';
```

error:

```
I am getting syntex eror at or near null.[SQL_state==NULL] in redshift.
```

I believe the error I'm experiencing is due to the structure of my JSON file.Does anyone have any advice on how to identify and resolve the issue?  Any ideas or suggestions would be greatly appreciated.

I'm looking to create a table based on the JSON file.

Redshift table

```
| name     | age      | dif      |
| -------- | -------- | -------- |
| abc      | 23       |23.89     |
| pop      | 28       |98.89     |
```

Comment: A typo I expect - the second column in your create table statement should be "age".  I think the issue is that your json file contains a single object - an array.  This array has objects in it but it isn't formatted to be read into Redshift.  A simple file on the source file side would be to remove the square brackets [ ].  Then you will have a file with flat objects.